# How to modify a string inside a struct in C?

Tags: c, string, struct, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I am trying to modify a field inside a struct. I have no trouble doing this with other types (i.e. `int`, `float` etc.) but `char *` is giving me problems. I think I have to do something like:

```
typedef struct{
    char *string_field;
} struct_name;

struct_name *struct_name1;
struct_name1 = (struct_name *) malloc(sizeof(struct_name));
strcpy(struct_name1->string_field, new_string);

printf("New string: %s\n", struct_name1->string_field);
```

But this gives me a segmentation fault. What reason do you think I would get this problem for? Initially, I thought maybe the `char *string_field` was not big enough to copy to, but I changed the size of it manually to be of size 100 (more than enough) and I still get this problem.

Comment: 1. Don't cast `malloc()`. 2. `struct_name1->string_field` is uninitialized. Passing it to a function (`strcpy(...)`) has undefined behavior.

Comment: 3. This has nothing to do with structs. You need to review the basics of pointers in C.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the structure *and* the string.

Comment: Whenever you have a pointer, if you can't answer the question "What block of memory does this point to?" -- bad things will happen.... `string_field` is a pointer -- pointing to what?

Answer (score 4):

You reserve memory for your struct, which comprises a pointer to a string, but not the space for a string's content. Reserve memory for the string content and let your struct's pointer point to it; then you can copy `newstring`'s content into that memory:

```
struct_name1->string_field = malloc(strlen(new_string)+1);
strcpy(struct_name1->string_field, new_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory for the structure as well as for the string.
In example below there is a room for 63 characters in the string.
Remember to free the allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char *string_field;
} struct_name;

int main()
{
   struct_name *struct_name1;
    struct_name1 =  malloc(sizeof(struct_name));
    struct_name1->string_field = malloc(64*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(struct_name1->string_field, "new_string");

    printf("New string: %s\n", struct_name1->string_field);

    free(struct_name1->string_field);
    free(struct_name1);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
New string: new_string
```